# Checking a file exists (and ignoring case) in Python

Tags: python, case-sensitive

I have a Python script and I want to check if a file exists, but I want to ignore case

eg.

```
path = '/Path/To/File.log'
if os.path.isfile(path):
   return true
```

The directory may look like this "/path/TO/fILe.log". But the above should still return true.

Comment: The semantics of cast-sensitivity on filename compares is encoded in the operating system and the filesystem, not in the application. What OS and filesystem are you using?

Comment: what do you want to do if /path/To/file and /path/tO/file both exist ? This is probably OS dependant, but then you don't really know which file you are reffering to.

Comment: @Rob filesystem is nfs on a Red Hat 4.4.6-4

Comment: @ascobol - return true if both exist

Comment: There is not a practical solution to your problem as stated. Can you tell us *why* you want to do this thing? Perhaps we can help with your actual problem.

Comment: @Rob I've been provided with a rather large list of paths, and I need to check if they exist, unfortunately the cases are inconsistant

Comment: You could use some kind of recursion and check top-to-bottom if any matches exist...

Comment: that would be expensive, I was hoping there may be a simple solution which eluded me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generate one-time a set `S` of all absolute paths in the filesystem using `os.walk`, lowering them all as you collect them using `str.lower`.
2. Iterate through your large list of paths to check for existing, checking with `if my_path.lower() in S`.
3. (Optional)  Go and interrogate whoever provided you the list with inconsistent cases.  It sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), there may be some strange reason for this and an easier way out.